# SQL - Subtraction within a Common Table Expression,

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

------ SOLVED  --------

---

Instead of trying to perform the subtraction within the scope of the CTE, I just had to place it into the sub query which was using this particular CTE, in the main select list.

The Problem was, `InnerOQLI.FreePlaceCount is not being recognized, since it hasn't been defined within the scope of the CTE and is only being used in the Exists statement.

---

------ PROBLEM ----------

This is the first time I've used CTE's, I've joined multiple CTE's together so that I can retrieve an overall total in a single column.

I need to perform a subtraction within one of the CTE's

I first wrote it like this

```
MyCount2
AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        O.ID AS OrderID,
            (   
            (
            (SELECT SUM(InnerOC.[Count])
                FROM Order InnerO
                INNER JOIN SubOrder InnerSO ON InnerO.ID = InnerSO.OrderID
                INNER JOIN OrderComponent InnerOC ON SO.ID = OC.SubOrderID
                WHERE OC.OrderComponentTypeID IN (1,2,4,5)
                AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OrderQuoteLineItem InnerOQLI 
                WHERE InnerOQLI.OrderQuoteLineItemTypeID = 9 AND Order.ID = InnerO.ID)
                AND Inner0.ID = ).ID)  

            )

            - --< Minus Here

            OQLI.FreePlaceCount

            ) AS [SHPCommExpression2]

    FROM Order O
        INNER JOIN SubOrder SO ON O.ID = SO.OrderID
        INNER JOIN OrderComponent OC ON SO.ID = OC.SubOrderID
        INNER JOIN OrderQuoteLineItem OQLI ON SO.ID = 0QLI.SubOrderID

),
```

Without going into to much detail, this brings back incorrect data because of repeated rows in the main query. (I believe it cos of the same joins within the main query)

So I then wrote this

```
MyCount2
AS
    (SELECT InnerO.ID AS OrderID
        SUM(InnerOC.[Count]
        - InnerOQLI.FreePlaceCount) --- Tried to place subtraction here ----
        AS [SHPCommExpression12])

        FROM Order InnerO
        INNER JOIN SubOrder InnerSO ON InnerO.ID = InnerSO.OrderID
        INNER JOIN OrderComponent InnerOC ON SO.ID = OC.SubOrderID
        WHERE OC.OrderComponentTypeID IN (1,2,4,5)
        AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM OrderQuoteLineItem InnerOQLI 
        WHERE InnerOQLI.OrderQuoteLineItemTypeID = 9 AND Order.ID = InnerO.ID)
        GROUP BY InnerO.ID)
    ),
```

You can see where I've attempted to perform the subtraction, but It doesn't recognize InnerOQLI, where I've tried to add it to perform the subtraction.  I can't work out how to correct this, I realize that it cant fully recognize the `InnerOQLI` since it's in the Exists statement, Is there away around this? If anyone could help I'd appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: You receive an error or what?

Comment: It doesn't recognize InnerOQLI, where I've tried to add it to perform the subtraction

Comment: And what is `InnerBLQI`? I don't see it anywhere else. Please, edit your question. You need to be VERY clear and show just relevant part of code.

Comment: Yep Sorry It should be InnerOQLI

Comment: I've managed to fix it. I just had to put the subtraction within the main select list, outside the scope of the CTE and it worked.

Comment: If you've solved your own problem, you should post your solution as an answer, give it a day or two for others post their ideas, then accept the best answer - even if it is your own!

Comment: Ahh I didn't know, Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to perform the subtraction within the scope of the CTE, I just had to place it into the sub query which was using this particular CTE, in the main select list.

The Problem was, `InnerOQLI.FreePlaceCount is not being recognized, since it hasn't been defined within the scope of the CTE and is only being used in the Exists statement.